# How to insert a space in a random letter/number generator and align the output?

Tags: java

My program is supposed to print 40 random uppercase letters, printing ten per line, and then 40 random single digits also printed 10 per line.

My code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Random uppercase letters: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++ ) {
            System.out.print(randomLetter()); 
            if(i % 10 == 0) 
                System.out.print("\n");
        }   
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Random single digits: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            System.out.print(randomNumber());
            if(i % 10 == 0) 
                System.out.print("\n"); 
        }
    }

    public static char randomLetter(){
        int letter = (int) (Math.random()*26) + (int) 'A';
        return (char)letter;
    }
    public static char randomNumber(){
        int number = (int)(Math.random()*10) + (int) '0';
        return (char)number;
    }   
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
Random uppercase letters: 
Q
OWGUAPCUQE
IFLKOJMDMF
WOBJDBIDXR
VVOTGLXCU

Random single digits: 
7
6391852294
0333642849
3598298753
914350922
```

Can I please get an explanation on why the Q and 7 are on a line all by themselves, and how can I fix it?
Also, how can I insert a space between each of the letters and digits?

Comment: Think about what `i % 10 == 0` evaluates to for different values of `i`. The loop starts at `i = 0`, so what is `i % 10` when `i` is `0`? Etc.

Comment: Hint: you can figure such things by running your program in a debugger. It is fine to ask other people for help, but in such situations, you learn more trying to figure stuff by you doing something ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start using IDE debugger, so that you understand the flow.

`i` starts with zero, and first `i%10==0` comes true, hence the first new line is printed

Instead start the loop with 1 and end with <=40. Also you can append space within the `print` method

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Program1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Random uppercase letters: ");
    for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++ ) {
        System.out.print(randomLetter()+" "); 
        if(i % 10 == 0) 
            System.out.print("\n");
    }   
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Random single digits: ");
    for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        System.out.print(randomNumber()+ " ");
        if(i % 10 == 0) 
            System.out.print("\n"); 
    }
}

public static char randomLetter(){
    int letter = (int) (Math.random()*26) + (int) 'A';
    return (char)letter;
}
public static char randomNumber(){
    int number = (int)(Math.random()*10) + (int) '0';
    return (char)number;
}   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I had tried the + " " in the print statement earlier and it didn't work but it's fine now.

Comment: @RohithL. if the answer solves your purpose, plz mark it as answered

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that 0 / 10 = 0. Thus, the modulus function holds. Add a condition to ensure that `i != 0` as well other than the modulus. That should take care of it.